# Opening the youngest file in a folder VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I am trying to open the latest file (date modified) in a folder. The code uses a loop to go through the files and find the latest modified which it does however when it comes to open the file using 'Workbooks.Open strFilename' it says the file (which it has already identified as the 'youngest' file could not be found. This doesn't make sense to me as the error message says the file 'test young' - the file name could not be found, but it clearly found it during the loop.

```
Sub copynewdata()

Dim FileSys As FileSystemObject
Dim objFile As File
Dim myFolder
Dim strFilename As String
Dim dteFile As Date

Dim Ref As Object, CheckRefEnabled%
CheckRefEnabled = 0
With ThisWorkbook
    For Each Ref In .VBProject.References
        If Ref.Name = "Scripting" Then
            CheckRefEnabled = 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Ref
    If CheckRefEnabled = 0 Then
        .VBProject.References.AddFromGUID "{420B2830-E718-11CF-893D-00A0C9054228}", 1, 0
    End If
End With
    
'set path for files - change for your folder
Const myDir As String = "\\C:\Test"

'set up filesys objects
Set FileSys = New FileSystemObject
Set myFolder = FileSys.GetFolder(myDir)
    
'loop through each file and get date last modified. If largest date then store Filename
dteFile = DateSerial(1900, 1, 1)
For Each objFile In myFolder.Files
    If objFile.DateLastModified > dteFile Then
        dteFile = objFile.DateLastModified
        strFilename = objFile.Name
    End If
Next objFile
Workbooks.Open strFilename
'Set Source_Workbook = Workbooks(strFilename).Open(Target_Path)
        
Set FileSys = Nothing
Set myFolder = Nothing

End Sub
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `strFilename`, you have the name of the file - but without the path. Change the open-command to

`Workbooks.Open myDir & "\" & strFilename`